# Retrieve a bean in Spring using java.lang.annotation in runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I have a list of annotations which I have retrieved using

```
java.lang.reflect.Method.getDeclaredAnnotations()
```

Using these annotations, how can I retrieve spring beans which are *tagged*
with these annotations?

Pseudo code:

```
public interface Work{...}

@Component
@A1
public class SpringBean1 implements Work{}

@Component
@A2
public class SpringBean2 implements Work{}

public class Test 
{

  public void doSomething() 
  {

    Annotation[] annotations = getAnnotationsListUsingReflection();

    for(Annotation annotation: annotations) 
    {
      Work work = /* Retrieve bean using annotation, how to do this? */
      work.xyz(); 
      ......
    }    

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your annotations are annotating the bean types and not their methods, you can use [`ListableBeanFactory#getBeanNamesForAnnotation(Class)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeanNamesForAnnotation-java.lang.Class-).

> Find all names of beans whose `Class` has the supplied `Annotation` type,
>   without creating any bean instances yet.

`AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` is one implementation of that interface.

Given such an instance

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = ...;
String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanNamesForAnnotation(Annotation.class);
```

Then iterate through the bean names and get each bean

```
for (String beanName : beanNames) {
    Object bean = ctx.getBean(beanName);
    // use it
}
```

Alternatively, [`ListableBeanFactory#getBeansWithAnnotation(Class)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeansWithAnnotation-java.lang.Class-) can do the work for you:

> Find all beans whose `Class` has the supplied `Annotation` type, returning
>   a `Map` of bean names with corresponding bean instances.